# how to schedule a python script

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I want to Schedule a python script.

I need help in ACTIONS tab: Here I have provided the below
[image: please check the below]

I'm unable to run the task.
Please assist.

Comment: I think you will have better luck with that on superuser.  It's not a programming question.  If your path to python and to the script is correct that ought to work.

Comment: Can you assist me with what should I mention in Actions tab

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows 10 system with standard Anaconda installation, I ran the
following action, leaving all the other screens defaulted, except for
selecting trigger at a certain time for a one-time run:

- Program/script: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
- Add arguments: "try csv 2.py" (double quotes since spaces in script name)
- Start in: C:...\folder (in your case: C:\helloo)

On first try, I ran this task with the arguments without double quotes; this resulted in Last Run Result `(0x2)`. I think this is the return code from execution, with 0 being success.

Comment: I tried it , But not working :( ,getting the error ox2

Comment: See updated answer. `(0x2)` is an error. What happens if you run this script from the command prompt?

Comment: from command prompt it is working fine . I can able to get the output 
in mail.py I have given the code of sending mail from outlook .

Comment: OK. Could it be that the kind of code in the program cannot be done in a background task. The program I tested with creates a file in the current folder. Maybe start with something basic like that, and see if that works in a background task?